# EF6 "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." when adding to context

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, .net-4.5, dbcontext

```
            SHIPMENT_RESOLUTION srNew = CreateNextResolution(sr);

            context.SHIPMENT_RESOLUTION.Add(srNew);
```

Produces this stack trace, (trimmed to only show what's important)

```
    System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
    HResult=-2146233079
    Message=Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
    Source=System.Core
  StackTrace:
       at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.TakeSnapshotOfRelationships()
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityWrapperWithoutRelationships`1.TakeSnapshotOfRelationships(EntityEntry entry)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AddSingleObject(EntitySet entitySet, IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, String argumentName)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AddObject(String entitySetName, Object entity)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.<>c__DisplayClassd.<Add>b__c()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
       at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
```

I do have a circular reference here.
SHIPMENT_RESOLUTION contains SHIPMENT, which contains SHIPMENT_RESOLUTION, but I've only seen that as a bug on EF 4.1.
In my case I'm on EF6.

In this case, the called function just copies some of the properties to the newly created adn returned object, and iterates a value by one.